# Create binding for #define pointer address

Tags: vala, vapi

Creating some custom vapi defs with the help of the excellent write up in [the Vala manual](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ManualBindings#Functions) as my guide.  But I'm not sure how to translate C function-like macros like these:

```c
// GPIO setup macros. Always use INP_GPIO(x) before using OUT_GPIO(x) or SET_GPIO_ALT(x,y)
#define INP_GPIO(g) *(gpio+((g)/10)) &= ~(7<<(((g)%10)*3))
#define OUT_GPIO(g) *(gpio+((g)/10)) |=  (1<<(((g)%10)*3))
#define SET_GPIO_ALT(g,a) *(gpio+(((g)/10))) |= (((a)<=3?(a)+4:(a)==4?3:2)<<(((g)%10)*3))
#define GPIO_SET *(gpio+7)  // sets   bits which are 1 ignores bits which are 0
#define GPIO_CLR *(gpio+10) // clears bits which are 1 ignores bits which are 0
#define GET_GPIO(g) (*(gpio+13)&(1<<g)) // 0 if LOW, (1<<g) if HIGH
#define GPIO_PULL *(gpio+37) // Pull up/pull down
#define GPIO_PULLCLK0 *(gpio+38) // Pull up/pull down clock
```

The C code declares `gpio` this way:

```
// I/O access
volatile unsigned *gpio;
```

Should I declare the macro `INP_GPIO(g)` as a void function, i.e.

```c
[CCode (cname = "INP_GPIO")]
public void inp_gpio(int val);
```

or as a delegate, like below?

```c
public delegate void inp_gpio(int val);
```

Which conditions should I follow when deriving the Vala type from C code for a VAPI file?

**Update**: As I continue to work on my valaIOT project, the vapis mentioned below are maintained at *https://gitlab.com/gpaslanis/valaiot/tree/master/vapis*. Please post recommendations/corrections at the site. I hope you find them helpful.

Comment: You'd probably have better luck writing some wrappers in C to bind to rather than trying to bind a macro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question! The code looks like it is directly accessing the GPIO memory address and seems to be from [RPi GPIO Code Samples - Direct register access](https://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Code_Samples#Direct_register_access). The C pre-processor is exchanging `INP_GPIO(g)` for an expression using the `&=` operator. The expression does a bitwise operation on the memory location calculated on the left hand side of the operator.

All Vala needs to do is make sure `INP_GPIO(g)` is written to the C file and then the C pre-processor does the exchange. So the correct binding would be something like:

```
[CCode (cname = "INP_GPIO")]
public void inp_gpio(int pin);
```

A delegate in Vala is a function pointer in C and the code isn't going to call the memory address, but write a value to it. It's not a function pointer in C and so shouldn't be bound as a delegate in Vala.

Using GPIOs is a great use case for Vala. You may want to consider using the Linux kernel user space API instead. This recently changed with Linux 4.8 and isn't in the Vala `linux.vapi`. So a patch would be welcome for using [linux/include/uapi/linux/gpio.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/gpio.h) with Vala. It's essentially a file interface to `/dev/gpiochipx` with various IOCTLs to manipulate it. For more details see these [slides](https://kernel-recipes.org/en/2018/talks/new-gpio-interface-for-user-space/). If you understand GMainContext and GSource I think it would be possible to write a Vala GSource with [g_source_add_unix_fd](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-add-unix-fd). This would trigger an event in the GMainContext when there is a change in a GPIO line. An event being just another name for a callback. This would be a good way of implementing higher level application code in response to inputs on GPIO lines. A GMainContext is created behind the scenes when using GMainLoop or GApplication. The documentation for Vala needs to done though.

There is also [`libgpiod`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git/about/) that provides a user space library to interface with the kernel character device interface. For Vala this would mean writing a [libgpiod.vapi](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git/tree/libgpiod.pc.in) to use [gpiod.h](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git/tree/include/gpiod.h). libgpiod also has command line tools and [this article](https://www.beyondlogic.org/an-introduction-to-chardev-gpio-and-libgpiod-on-the-raspberry-pi/) give a nice summary of those.